# No type or protocol named AKNode/AKToggleable

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to extend AKNode and AKToggelable and this error appears on Project-Swift.h file

What is the way to do this?

My class is

```
class AKCustom: AKNode, AKToggleable, AKComponent, AKInput {
public typealias AKAudioUnitType = AKBalancerDeplikeAudioUnit

public static let ComponentDescription = AudioComponentDescription(mixer: "dpba")

private var internalAU: AKAudioUnitType?


open dynamic var isStarted: Bool {
    return internalAU?.isPlaying() ?? false
}

public init( _ input: AKNode? = nil) {
    _Self.register()
    super.init()
    AVAudioUnit._instantiate(with: _Self.ComponentDescription) { [weak self] avAudioUnit in

        self?.avAudioNode = avAudioUnit
        self?.internalAU = avAudioUnit.auAudioUnit as? AKAudioUnitType

        input?.connect(to: self!)
    }
}

open func start() {
    internalAU?.start()
}

open func stop() {
    internalAU?.stop()
}
}
```

And error messages in Project-Swift.h file:

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'AKNode', superclass of 'AKCustom'

No type or protocol named 'AKToggleable'
```

Comment: What is AKNode? What framework is it in?

Comment: AKNode is a class from AudioKit Framework
/// Parent class for all nodes in AudioKit
@objc open class AKNode : NSObject {
}

Comment: It looks like it's not part of the standard iOS frameworks and needs to be installed... http://audiokit.io/docs/index.html The iOS framework is `CoreAudioKit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `#import "AudioKit/AudioKit-Swift.h"` to `PROJECT-Bridging-Header.h`. Then `AKNode` will be accessible at `Project-Swift.h`.

Comment: This may work but its not necessary in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the AudioKit folder is a "Developer" folder that has examples for "Extending AudioKit" on both iOS and Mac.  That's probably the best place to start.  Make sure you're including the source as a framework properly - the examples in this folder show you how to do it either with source directly or the precompiled framework.